# Dual Booting Ubuntu 13.10 with Windows 7 From USB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb

I formatted my PC and installed Win7. I want to dual boot with Ubuntu 13.10. After I burn the iso file to 8GB USB stick with "iso to usb", restarted and I get this error:

> BOOTMGR is missing
>
> Press any key to restart

I tried formatting my USB (FAT32) but it's still not working.

Thanks for your time. Any ideas?

edit #2: There is a checkbox " Bootable, only supports Windows ISO image. " which the last time I left unchecked before burning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What program are you using to create the bootable USB? I would suggest UNetbootin if you're not using it. Never had this sort of problem with that program. Download for Windows can be found [here:](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I used "ISO to USB", let's try that. Thanks!

Comment: FYI, it still has be formatted in FAT32.

Comment: Okay, but I can't see Ubuntu 13.10 on the distributions list.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about that. Select the "Diskimage" radio button at the bottom and select your Ubuntu .iso. This is how I've always done it.

Comment: Thanks, I have another question also. I've read some forums and people were saying that after 12.10 it was a "downgrade" not an upgrade to change to 13.10. I still think that using the latest version is better. What would you prefer?

Comment: I actually use 12.04 because it's LTS. Will probably upgrade to 14.04 LTS when it's available in April. It all comes down to personal preference though.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) or [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) (this can also make Bootable **Windows** in USB).Both of them works fine to make of any **Linux Live USB** ...

Comment: I used Unetbootin when I had this problem. I decided to install 12.04 until 13.04 comes out. Now everything goes well. Still thanks for your answer it would be useful for someone.